# No Hang Detection log for iOS App but numbers do pop up showing there is a hang

Tags: ios, freeze

When testing my app on real device, I got numbers pop up, which to my understanding indicates time of hang when loading the view in milliseconds, like this
[image]

But when checking Settings - Developer - Hang Detection, there says no detected hangs
[image]

I just can't find out which part is wrong after Googling around. Could someone please help me understand this?

After turn off hang detection in settings, those numbers will not appear again, so I guess it is what I think it is, time of hanging, right?

Comment: Why do you think that number represents information about hangs? Try to profile the app with Instruments and see if really there are hangs (micro or macro) in your app.

Comment: @Cristik I tried time profiler, which shows no hang at all... Guess I should be happy about it. But the reason I suspect those numbers indicate time of hangs is, when I turn off hang detection in  Settings - Developer, those numbers won't be shown. Turn it on again, they appear again, that must mean something right?

Comment: The number does represent the hang duration and the logs should appear in Settings. I'm not getting any new logs in the latest iOS so something is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that number represents how long the app is hanging, and there should be corresponding logs in settings. Can you please reproduce the issue, submit feedback, and share the FeedbackID? Thank you!

Opening this link in Safari is the easiest way:

applefeedback://inbox?make_visible=1

Comment: Hi BB, here is the feedback ID: FB13460238. Thx

Comment: Looks like it's missing diagnostics. You can include them with `Add More Information > Add Attachment > Device Diagnostics`

Comment: Hey there, I've attached diagnostics a few days ago. Is there any update on this?

Comment: @BB-Guitar Another report added with feedback ID FB13514381 (still uploading)